# Communicating with a remote server via microsoft Teams

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, datadog

**Scenario:**

I have a remote server which is monitored (via DataDog) and sends out a warning when some anomaly is detected. This warning can be fetched via a webhook. Now I want to connect that webhook (https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/webhooks/) with MS Teams (probably via Bot), to receive a warning. Then I want to send a command back to the remote server to resolve the warning.

**Technology:**

MS Teams, Python flask/Django, remote server

**Expected Results:**

I can receive a warning from my remote server to MS Teams via a bot. Then send a command back to the remote server. My initial plan is doing this using Python Flask/Django but not tied to a specific language.

**Environment:**

Remote server is a LINUX based system. we have a internal network that is used within our company, so might need to resolve a firewall problem potentially (idk whole lot about it tho).

**Things I have tried:**

I just want to see if this is possible or not, so i havent coded up any. But I found some information relevant to our problem:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/webhooks/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors

One last note, I am not also tied down to Teams bot. Our company also uses Azure Devops, so that is another resource I can use to realize the solution.

Btw, this question was posted on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/44217/communicating-with-a-remote-server-via-teams.html) but was told to post on MSDN, but I couldn't find an appropriate forum. Hence, I am posting on stack overflow instead

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: @donnie, What is your question here. In result, you mentioned - you receive these values from datadog and can send it to Azure bot.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT. Oh, that was meant to be an "expected" result. Not an actual result. I changed the title to Expected Result so that it is not confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As you have limited requirements, you could achieve this without a bot.

MS Teams has income and outgoing webhooks. You could create a [Incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) inside a Teams channel. It provides an URL which you could use inside the monitoring remote server and POST the message in JSON format to the webhook url. It will be posted in teams channel like below
[image]

For sending message back to the server you need to configure the [Outgoing webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook) in the channel.